# Drupal Commerce : modify Collection Products view

Tags: commerce

In my webshop, I use Price Savings formatter for my discounts. In the product page, it shows list price, price with discount and savings. 
In the Category overview (Collection Products view), it only shows the list price, without the discount.

I'm trying to get the category overview to show either discounted price, or a striked through list price + discounted price.
Because now, people won't notice if something is discounted until they open the product page. 
I can't seem to find any simple solution anywhere, while this seems as a rather essential part of a webshop.

I've already tried editing the view, but the difficulty level goes beyond my skill at the moment. Can anyone explain how I can edit or change the fields that are shown in the Collection Products view, because it only has taxonomy name and global:custom text as fields. I've looked through the tpl files for the view, but nowhere is there a mention of which fields from the database should be shown.